# PHP htaccess wrong with URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://localhost/customers/website/jobs/28

When for an example the URL above is visited and my code is used, it goes to: http://localhost/customers/website/jobs/startpage

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["startpage"])) {

    }else{
        header("Location: startpage");
    }
```

But if I do `header("Location: /startpage");` it becomes http://localhost/startpage

My Htacess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /customers/website/

RewriteRule ^startpage/?$    startpage.php    [NC,L]
```

How can I make it go to http://localhost/customers/website/startpage?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Where is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: it's located at /customers/website/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PHP for this. You can do this in htaccess itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /customers/website/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !startpage
RewriteRule !^startpage/?$ startpage [L,NC,CO=startpage:1:%{HTTP_HOST},R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} startpage
RewriteRule ^startpage/?$ startpage.php [L]
```

and remove your `header` function call from PHP code.

---

If you will want to do this in PHP itself then use:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["startpage"])) {
   //
} else {
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER["BASE"] . "startpage");
}
```

and keep same rewrite rule shown in question.